# EntityFramework EntityObject current changing question

Tags: entity-framework

I want to track changes when current record changes in ObjectSet. Maybe something like BindingSource.CurrentChanged. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: EF already track changes so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to check is there some changes in object when i switch to another object.

Comment: Is it a WinForm app? You should know if user did any changes to the object, shouldn't you? Nobody else can change the object opened by the user.

Comment: Yes Ladislav, it is WinForm app. I want prevent user from row exiting with BindingNavigator if object have unsaved changes. I can do this stuff in WinForm app, but i think this is not correctly in terms of architecture.

Comment: So you want save changes to each object separately?

Comment: Yes, in my case i want save changes separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get state of any entity you can just call:

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(editedEntity).State
```